# How to echo object function?

Tags: php, function

Fairly new to PHP. Why doesn't the following work when trying to call the object's function get_colour()?
I'm ultimately trying to call the object's function on a button click.

```
echo $newToy->get_colour(); //Works
echo "<h1>$newToy->get_colour()</h1>"; //Doesnt work
echo "<button onclick='$newToy->get_colour();'>Display</button>"; //Doesnt work
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you expect arbitrary code in string literals to be executed? Variable interpolation is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Just pop it out of quotes if you know it returns a string: `echo "<h1>". $newToy->get_colour() ."</h1>";`

Comment: So in the second line, the entire part inside quotes is known as a string, and whatever is inside will be printed exactly as is. In the third line, you have added single quotes, which is simply a way to still have quotation marks inside a string. For example, if you wanted to print "There and back again" - Bilbo Baggins, you would print "'There and back again' - Bilbo Baggins".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `echo "<h1>".$newToy->get_colour()."</h1>";`  but on a button its impossible to call php object function directly in javascript just use ajax post or get to call php function in javascript. Onclick function in a button is a javascript.